# Why is Discord Bot not being added to my server?

Tags: debugging, automation, discord, permissions, bots

So I have created a discord bot and I want to add it to my discord server. I have given it admin privileges and I've

given it all available scopes as seen in this image

This is my redirect **URI** that I base my invite link on https://discord.com/channels/1190622550695358556/1190622551307731006

[image]

I've configured the permissions of my server I've added in all the available scopes and given admin privileges

to my bot.

The invite link seems to work alright except for the fact that I'm using a discord url as my redirect link but

the bot does not appear in my server.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be the case?

I've given my bot all the privileged Gateway Intents and my permissions integer is 8 so admin level permissions.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it. It turns out that I just needed a fresh environment. I created a new bot and it worked perfectly. Sometimes it's as simple as resetting things.